# DataOutputStream cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, sockets

```
DataOutputStream salida;

salida  = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

> Error:(35, 24) java: DataOutputStream is abstract; cannot be
>   instantiated

Comment: Is this `java.io.DataOutputStream`, or some other class that a library is providing? If it's the java.io one, it shouldn't be abstract. If it's another one, you'll need to tell us which library -- but you should first look at the library's documentation to try and find an appropriate concrete subclass.

Comment: try accessing DataOutputStream using ``java.io.DataOutputStream``

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the package `java.io.*`. `DataOutputStream` is in that package.

Answer (score 1):

you are using some other library for `DataOutputStream`.
use this

```
    java.io.DataOutputStream salida;
    salida  = new java.io.DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```